# jcraft execute shell command returns exit status 127

Tags: shell, ssh, server

I am trying to run shell script 
(/sasdata/sasconfig/Lev1/Applications/SASEnterpriseGRCAdminTools/6.1/dbscripts/addxlsdata.sh -t /sasdata/Data/Loaders/IFT_tst_loader2.xls)
on remote server with java, using jcraft, but in answer I have exit status 127. I tried to run simple command "date" with my method - and all was good. Then I tried to run this script by entering command in terminal, and all was ok too. Also I tried to execute "cd" to path with addxlsdata.sh and there run 
./addxlsdata.sh -t /sasdata/Data/Loaders/IFT_tst_loader2.xls 
and again there was 127 exit status.
What the problem it can be?

Here is my method:

```
public static void executeShell(String shellScriptCommand, String userName, String password, String server) {
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    LOG.info("Creating session, user: " + userName);
    JSch jSch = new JSch();
    Session session = jSch.getSession(userName, server, sshPort);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.connect();
    LOG.info("Opening exec channel");
    ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

    LOG.info("Creating InputStream");
    InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();
    channelExec.setCommand("sh " + shellScriptCommand);
    LOG.info("Executing the shell script: " + shellScriptCommand);
    channelExec.connect();

    LOG.info("Reading the output from the input stream");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    CommonFunctions.freeze(3);
    while (reader.ready()) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        result.add(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    LOG.info("OUTPUT is " + result);

    LOG.info("Getting exit status");
    int exitStatus = channelExec.getExitStatus();
    LOG.info("Exit status is [" + exitStatus + "]");

    channelExec.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
} catch (JSchException | IOException e) {
    LOG.error(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
    throw new AutotestError("Ошибка при выпонении shell скрипта", e);
}
```

}

I find out one thing. This *.sh file have another script inside "./runjava.sh". Maybe here is the problem

It seems that it is my fault in connect to wrong server. Despite that I use the same address in java and winscp, when I use ls in directory with the script in java and in terminal, I have different results

I think that I have found what the problem. When I execute "cd /" in java and then "pwd", the output is "/home/username". I can't exit from Home directory to root in java. In terminal I can do this with the same user

Answer (score 0):

Your java application has not permission to execute the script. Add the account (which run your java application) to the group which has ownership to script `./addxlsdata.sh`. Also provide necessary execute permission as well.

First go to the directory and execute `ls -ltr` and provide the detail information to your Unix admin and also provide the user id detail which run the java application to add that user to the proper group. It will work once you short out this.

Comment: Thank you for help. I think that I have found what the problem. When I execute "cd /" in java and then "pwd", the output is "/home/username". I can't exit from Home directory to root in java. Do you now how can I do this?

Comment: It is very clear here. Your java application does not have permission to execute "cd /" command. That means it has no access to root directory `/`. Ask your system admin. Once you set the permission it can do the `cd /` and even can execute the script.

Comment: Here the results of "ls -ltr" for files, I tried to execute
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sasinst sasinst    221 Sep 18  2014 addxlsdata.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sasinst sasinst   1254 Oct  5  2017 runjava.sh

Comment: @tomasomsk, that's not enough. Can you run your java application as root? Just try to run it as root and see. If you run the java application as root everything will be fine.

Comment: My java application work on my PC, not on server. I write auto tests, where I need to use shell scripts to prepare test data. How can I run java application as root? I run it from IDEA now.

Comment: Ask your unix admin for sudo authentication to execute your java application as root.

Comment: I thought that java connect to server as user sasinst and then try to execute commands. And if in terminal this user can cd to root so and java should do this

Answer (score 0):

It was my terrible fault. I invoked my method several times with different commands. I was running executeShell "cd /" and then executeShell "pwd". And of course second time it was a new session.